# Property 'dehydratedState' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, configuration, react-query

I got the error **Property 'dehydratedState' does not exist on type '{}'** when I added a pageProps dehydratedState . I was trying to configure the NextJs app for react Query using the documentation given in tanstack website https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/ssr#using-hydration

My Application is NextJS Typescript. Below is my configuration file

**_app.tsx**

```
// Client-side cache, shared for the whole session of the user in the browser.
const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

// interface MyAppProps extends AppProps {
//   emotionCache?: EmotionCache;
// }

type CustomPage = NextPage & {
  requiresAuth?: boolean;
  redirectUnauthenticatedTo?: string;
  dehydratedState?: any;
};
interface CustomAppProps extends Omit<AppProps, "Component"> {
  Component: CustomPage;
  emotionCache?: EmotionCache;

}
type ThemeMode = "light" | "dark";

const reactQueryConfig = {
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      cacheTime: 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false
    }
  }
}


export default function MyApp(props: CustomAppProps, theme: ThemeMode) {
  console.log("MyApp Rendered");

  const { Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps } = props;
  const [queryClient] = useState(() => new QueryClient(reactQueryConfig))
  return (
    <>

      <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
        <Head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        </Head>
        <ThemeModeProvider theme={theme}>

          {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
          <CssBaseline />
          <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            {/* Redux Store */}
            <Provider store={store}>
              <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
                <AuthProvider>
                  <Layout>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                    <ToastContainer position='top-center' hideProgressBar />
                  </Layout>
                </AuthProvider>
              </Hydrate>
            </Provider>
          </QueryClientProvider>
        </ThemeModeProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
    </>
  )
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  emotionCache: PropTypes.object,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Property 'dehydratedState' does not exist on type '{}' Error is coming from . Because the variable "dehydratedState" doesn't exists in pageProps object type. How to add dehydratedState to pageProps in Typescript ?

I tired to google and seach for this error solution. I did not found.

Comment: BTW I <3 Tanstack.com packages (Headless UI anyway, perfect code) but as we use NextJS, I'm migrating to SWR now (also Vercel, looks like even more appropriate) or not?

Answer (score 5):

This should work, at least for Next.js 13.1.6.
Try using `AppProps` as a ***Generic***, works for me with Next.js 13.1.6

I've just copied the solution from [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/40372#issuecomment-1279963091).

I think with this plan you can adapt it to your needs.
 good luck

```
// _app.tsx

import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { useState } from "react";
import {Hydrate,QueryClient,QueryClientProvider,type DehydratedState} from "react-query";

function App({ Component,pageProps,}: AppProps<{ dehydratedState: DehydratedState }>) {
  const [queryClient] = useState(() => new QueryClient());

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Hydrate>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you didn't pass the `pageProps` from your page file.

When you fetch the data using `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` then you pass props i.e. may be the data from API call. Then you pass it via props to your Page Component. That props is represented as `pageProps` in **_app.tsx**.

```
// pages/posts.tsx
import { dehydrate, QueryClient, useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()

  await queryClient.prefetchQuery(['posts'], getPosts)

  return {
    props: {
      // this was passed as pageProps in the _app.jsx
      dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Property 'dehydratedState' does not exist on type '{}'  Error  is coming from <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>. Because  the variable "dehydratedState" doesn't exists in  pageProps object type. How to add dehydratedState to pageProps in Typescript ?

Comment: You have to return the **props** object from the **getStaticProps** or **getServerSideProps** of the page component(the component define inside pages directory) of the app.